# What is the value of $\cosh(\sqrt{i})$?

Tags: hyperbolic-functions

> I am puzzling about the value of
>
> $$\cosh(\sqrt{i})$$

I know that

$$\sqrt{i} = \sqrt{\frac{1}{2}}+i\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}}$$

But how to go on with that? Are there also multiple values?

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: We need some more context. $\cosh(\sqrt{i})$ is an expression: are you trying to find its value? If so, you don't use the language of "solution", but of "evaluating". On the other hand, if there's an equals sign, and you're trying to find the value of a variable, you "solve it", you do not "evaluate it".

Comment: Do you know the formula for $\cosh?$  If so, what difficulty are you having?  If by $\sqrt{i}$ you mean the principal value, then there is only one value of the expression.

Answer (score 1):

Note that there are two possible values for $\sqrt{i}$, namely, $\pm\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}+\frac{i}{\sqrt{2}}\right)$. But since $\cosh$ is an even function, it doesn't matter which we choose. So we will work with finding $\cosh\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}+\frac{i}{\sqrt{2}}\right)$.

One easily verifies that $\cosh(a+bi)=\cosh a \cos b + i\sinh a\sin b$. Thus

$$\cosh\left(\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}+\tfrac{i}{\sqrt{2}}\right) = \boxed{\cosh \tfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \cos \tfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}} + i\sinh \tfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\sin \tfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}} \approx 0.9584 + 0.4986i.$$

---

**Addendum:** The rules for handling $f(-t)$ for trig functions $f$ have analogs for handling expressions like $f(it)$; moreover, the same rules apply to hyperbolic and trig functions alike. Let's explore them briefly.

We will distinguish between "c" and "s" functions. The familiar rules are:

- A factor of $-1$ can be pulled out of c-functions and disappears
- A factor of $-1$ can be pulled out of s-functions and remains

So: 
$\cos(-t)=\cos t$, and $\cosh(-t)=\cosh t$; 
$\sin(-t)=-\sin t$, and $\sinh(-t)=-\sinh t$.

The new rules are only slightly different:

- A factor of $i$ can be pulled out of c-functions and disappears, transforming the function
- A factor of $i$ can be pulled out of s-functions and remains, transforming the function

(here, "transforming" means changing trig to hyperbolic and vice versa).

So:
$\cos(it)=\cosh t$, and $\cosh(it)=\cos t$; $\sin(it)=i\sinh t$, and $\sinh(it)=i\sin t$.

Now it is easy to see what we said above:

$$\cosh(a+bi)=\cosh a\cosh(bi) + \sinh a\sinh(bi)$$
$$= (\cosh a)( \cos b) + (\sinh a) (i\sin b)$$
$$= \cosh a \cos b + i\sinh a\sin b$$
as desired.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the fact that: 
$$\cosh(x)=\frac{e^x+e^{-x}}{2}$$
And
$$\cos(x)=\frac{e^{ix}+e^{-ix}}{2}$$
Also make use of compound angle formula

Answer (score 0):

Use the definition $\cosh(x) = \frac{1}{2}(e^{x}+e^{-x})$ and the identity $\cosh(x+y) = \cosh(x)\cosh(y)+\sinh(x)\cosh(y)$ so

$$\cosh(\sqrt{i}) = \cosh(\sqrt{1/2})\cosh(i\sqrt{1/2}) + \sinh(\sqrt{1/2})\sinh(i\sqrt{1/2})$$
$$= \cosh(\sqrt{1/2})\cos(\sqrt{1/2}) + i\sinh(\sqrt{1/2})\sin(\sqrt{1/2})$$